# Complex Text Animations with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to figure out how the text animations used by https://storycreatorapp.com/demo (click on "text" on the left sidebar to view them) are created.

I understand that the drawtext filter usually is used to draw the text, but what filter is used to hide the text at the beginning of the text animation (most of the animations have text seemingly to slide out from nowhere right in the middle of the screen)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's using Lottie. You make those text animations in Premiere Pro and export as a JSON using Lottie plugin (bodymovin). Now you can edit that text and use Puppetter Lottie to get MP4.
https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/puppeteer-lottie

Answer (score 1):

Use ASS subtitles. You can create them with [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/).

Refer to the [override tags](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/) such as `\pos` (position), `\move`, `\clip` (mask) `\fade`, etc.

Then use `ffmpeg` with the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) or [ass](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ass) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf subtitles=subs.ass -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: I am generating ASS subtitles file and I am adding a position in the ```pos``` tag, My frontend app is built on Konvajs. The coordinates which are generated from the Konva are not usable in the ASS subtitle file. Because they are not synchronized, for example: if I send the x = 400, y= 200 from the front end the text is shown in the slightly upper from the middle right of the video. but the same coordinates make the text disappear from the video.
Conclusion, The cords on the frontend are slightly higher than the cords on the ASS ```pos``` tag.
I have also tried the filter of W and H.